# SUM from Select query then Show as another Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, join

I have this table that hold several products

[image]

And another table that holds the order for each product from above

[image]

How can i combine these tables and get the sum of each ord_Count per item and show it as another column, like this

[image]

To summarize it, I have a Items table that holds different products, and an Orders table that holds the orders for each product from the Items Table, then I want to have a query that combines both tables and show a my stock for each item from the Items table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(ord_count) AS Item_stock, itm_Code
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY itm_Code
```

To combine both table:

```
SELECT SUM(B.ord_count) AS Item_stock, B.itm_Code
FROM YourTable1 AS A
INNER JOIN YourTable2 AS B
    ON A.itm_Code = B.itm_Code
GROUP BY B.itm_Code
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to get the **Sum of the difference between the stocks and the requested products** which I just figured out just now. as simple as
`SUM(stock - requests_prod) as [Stock]` , which I didn't include above. I was puzzled and I didn't realize it can be done easily like this. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (item varchar(20),itemcode varchar(20))
insert into @t (item,itemcode)values ('choco','ckschoc'),('chocowafer','wfrchoc'),('chocostrrae','wfrstr')
declare @tt table (ordcnt int,itemcode varchar(20),dated date)
insert into @tt (ordcnt,itemcode,dated)values (20,'ckschoc','4/24/2015'),(10,'wfrchoc','4/24/2015'),(15,'wfrstr','4/24/2015')
,(30,'ckschoc','4/24/2015'),(20,'wfrstr','4/24/2015')
we can achieve the same result using sub query and corelated join query also
```

**Solution**

```
select t.itemcode,p.S  from @t t INNER JOIN   (
select itemcode,SUM(ordcnt)S from @tt
GROUP BY  itemcode)P
ON p.itemcode = t.itemcode
group by  t.itemcode,P.s

select t.itemcode,
(select SUM(tt.ordcnt)Cnt from @tt tt 
where tt.itemcode = t.itemcode 
group by tt.itemcode )Cnt from @t t
```